# How to add annotation to method runtime? Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem with the annotated method in interface

```
public interface CsvImportService {

    @Import
    void importFile(Long userId, String organizationId, MultipartFile file, String charset) throws Exception;
}
```

Implementation of interface

```
@Service
public class CsvImportServiceImpl implements CsvImportService {

    @Override
    public void importFile(Long userId, String organizationId, MultipartFile file, String charset) {
        ...
    }
 }
```

I tried to handle it by Spring AOP

```
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class ImportAspect {

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "@annotation(com.backend.annotations.Import)")
    public void handleImport(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        LOGGER.info("handle");
    }
}
```

But found out that annotation doesn't go to the impl, so I realized that I want to add the annotation to the realization method and started to write BPP

```
@Component
public class ImportAnnotationBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    Map<String, Class<?>> map = new HashMap<>();
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        Class<?> beanClass = bean.getClass();
        if (CsvImportService.class.isAssignableFrom(beanClass)) {
            map.put(beanName, beanClass);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        Class<?> beanClass = map.get(beanName);
        if (beanClass != null) {
            for (Method declaredMethod : CsvImportService.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                if (declaredMethod.isAnnotationPresent(Import.class)) {
                    Method importMethod = beanClass.getDeclaredMethod(declaredMethod.getName(), declaredMethod.getParameterTypes());
                    //TODO Add annotation to method
                }
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

And didn't find a reflection method that adds an annotation to the method.
how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: You cannot add annotations at runtime. The only way to do that is to use an annotation processor and do that compile time or use something at loadtime to modify the bytecode.

Comment: @M.Deinum Oh, too bad, maybe there is another way to handle interface annotation methods?